# Confusion about ideal class group computation

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, prime-factorization

I am attempting to compute the ideal class group of the real quadratic field $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{65})$, which has ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K = \Bbb Z\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{65}}{2}\right]$.

The discriminant $d_K$ of $K$ is

\begin{align}
d_K &= \begin{vmatrix} 1 &\frac{1 + \sqrt{65}}{2}\\ 1 &\frac{1 - \sqrt{65}}{2}\end{vmatrix}^2\\
&= 65
\end{align}

and, as a real quadratic field, there are no complex embeddings so the Minkowski bound $M_K$ is

\begin{align}
M_K &= \frac{2!}{2^2}\left( \frac{2}{\pi}\right)^0 \sqrt{65}\\
&\approx 4.03
\end{align}

so the ideal class group is generated by primes lying above $2$ and $3$. Checking the factorisation of $X^2 - X - 16 \bmod p$ for $p = 2, 3$ we get

$$X^2 - X - 16 \equiv X(X+1) \bmod 2\\
X^2 - X - 16 \equiv X^2 + 2X + 2 \bmod 3$$

so $2$ splits and $3$ is inert, so that $(2) = \mathfrak{p}_2\bar{\mathfrak{p}}_2$ and $(3) = \mathfrak{p}_3$ with $N(\mathfrak{p}_2) = N(\bar{\mathfrak{p}}_2) = 2$ and $N(\mathfrak{p}_3) = 9$.

Since $\mathfrak{p}_3$ is principal, it does not generate the ideal class group so we need only think about $\mathfrak{p}_2$.

What follows might seem like a silly quesion so brace yourselves!

> If the norm equation $a^2 + ab - 16b^2 = 2$ has solutions in the integers, should it have solutions modulo every prime?

I ask because the equation has no solutions modulo $5$, and this is perhaps a way of showing that there is no element of norm $2$ and so $\mathfrak{p}_2$ cannot be principal (the same computation shows there are no elements of norm $-2$, so this is also covered).

The confusion stems from the fact that the book I'm using quotes the ideal class $[(5, \sqrt{65})]$ as a generator for the class group, though this ideal has norm $5 > 4.03$, hence the confusion. In addition, following an argument by Keith Conrad in his expository papers, it seems that since $(5) = \mathfrak{p}_5^2$, if $\mathfrak{p}_5$ were principal we should be able to write

$$5 = (a + b\sqrt{65})^2 u$$

for some $u \in \mathcal{O}_K^\times$ and $a, b \in \frac{1}{2}\Bbb Z$. The units of $\mathcal{O}_K$ look like $\pm(8 + \sqrt{65})^n$ for $n \in \Bbb Z$, and since $N(8 + \sqrt{65}) = -1$, the units of norm $1$ have the form $(8 + \sqrt{65})^{2k}$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$. In particular, this means that the $u$ term in the above equation can be absorbed into the $(a+b\sqrt{65})^2$ term, but this implies that $\sqrt{5} \in \mathcal{O}_K$, and so $\mathfrak{p}_5$ is not principal, which seems to contradict the Minkowski bound.

Comment: How do you get from $(5)=p_5^2$ to $5=(a+b\sqrt{65})^2u$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Correct me if I'm wrong; since $\mathfrak{p}_5^2 = (5) $ and if $\mathfrak{p}_5 = (a + b\sqrt{65})$ then $\mathfrak{p}_5^2 = (5) = (a + b\sqrt{65})^2$, so that $5 = (a+b\sqrt{65})^2u$ for some unit $u$

Comment: But you report that Conrad claimed that $p_5$ was non-principal.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown This example isn't actually one in Conrad's expository papers, I just lifted the argument from an example that he had done. I'm claiming that $\mathfrak{p}_5$ is non-principal in this case from the same argument he uses. The difference is that in his example the field is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{82})$, which has a different ring of integers.

Comment: The class number is actually equal to $2$. Conrad computed the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-65})$ in Example $6$ [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf), not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{65})$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, but I'm trying to find the class group of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{65})$ and my question is more about how some of the things i've calculated might be incorrect (or at least where I've made some implicit assumptions that are not true). The argument about $\mathfrak{p}_5$ is taken from the same argument as in example $2$ of the same paper. The book "Introductory Algebraic Number Theory" by Alaca and Williams quotes $[(5, \sqrt{65})]$ as a generator for the class group of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{65})$, which is where a lot of my confusion stems from.

Comment: I can't verify your calculation of the unit group -- where there must be a problem as you point out, since $\sqrt 5$ surely is not in the field - but on the other points: if an integer equation has a solution it has a solution mod n for all n. Second, the Minkowski bound does not say that all ideals of larger norm are principal, just where you can find representatives for each class. $(2, \frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2})$ is non-principal but its square is. So the class group is of order $2$ and generated by any non-principal ideal.

Comment: @JohnBrevik Wonderful, so the fact that $a^2 + ab - 16b^2 = 2$ has no solutions mod $5$ (and the same for $-2$) shows that my $\mathfrak{p}_2$ is non-principal, right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's a valid and useful line of reasoning!

Comment: @JohnBrevik Perfect, in that case I think the problem is sorted. I thought that $(5, \sqrt{65})$ had to be principal because it has norm greater than the Minkowski bound. The fundamental unit I quoted is correct, so this argument appears to work to show that $(5, \sqrt{65})$ is non-principal, and so from what you say, I can take it as a representative for the ideal class of order $2$ in the class group. Thanks!

Comment: I thought a little more about this problem: Just as an exercise to get used to what to expect with these class group calculations, you may amuse yourself by verifying that $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2})\cdot(5+\sqrt{65}) = 2\cdot (5, \sqrt{65})$ -- thus they differ by factors of principal ideals and so are equal in the class group.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $(5,\sqrt{65})$ has a norm above the Minkowski bound does not imply it must be principal. Rather, the ideal cannot generate any more classes than other ideals whose norms are lower. Here the relevant ideals within the Minkowski bound are:

$(3)$, which is inert

$(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2})$, which gives a principal ideal when squared.

Thereby the integral domain must be class 2 and have ideal class group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and any ideal with a higher norm must also be principal or give a principal ideal when squared. The latter is what applies to $(5,\sqrt{65})$.